# Como instalar Node.js v.10 no Linux (16.04 LTS)

Tags: node.js, linux

Estou seguindo a documentação no site oficial do [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions-enterprise-linux-fedora-and-snap-packages) para a instalação do mesmo em um ambiente **Linux com distribuição Ubuntu**, que por sua vez redireciona para esta página no [github](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debmanual) que demonstra os seguintes comandos necessários para a instalação via terminal:

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Os comandos funcionam e é instalado o node, porém, na versão **`4.2.6`**.

Gostaria de saber como faço para que seja instalada a versão **`10`**, pois nessa versão instalada quando instalo também o npm vem com uma versão bem mais antiga e não consigo instalar o Angular.

> Sugestões serão bem-vindas, inclusive com a instalação do Node sem ser via terminal também.

Comment: Acho que resolvi o seu problema: Eu estou terminando de instalar em uma versão 16.04.11 do Ubuntu. Deixa eu terminar de instalar, não tem nada no sistema ele tá puxando muita coisa, dou uma conferida e te passo a solução.

Comment: Opa Augusto agradeceria muito, já tentei de tudo e nada resolveu até o momento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instalei um Ubuntu 16.04.11 com o mínimo possível.

Como usuário root primeira coisa que fiz replicar o seu primeiro comando:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
```

em seguida mudei a linha de comando para...

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential
```

...de forma a buscar e resolver conflitos de dependência(por isso que demorei):

Depois da instalação

```
root@usr:/# nodejs --version
v10.15.3
root@usr:/# npm --version
6.4.1
```

Comment: Espero ter lhe ajudado.

Comment: Deu certo Augusto, ajudou muito. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Secesso em sua empreitada.

Comment: Opa, a todos nós!